# Is it legit to use a point estimate along with a conformal predictive interval from a quantile regressor?

Tags: predictive-models, loss-functions, prediction-interval, quantile-regression, point-estimation

I have a quantile regression model that gives me prediction intervals (PI), and I also need to have a point estimate for all sorts of reasons (or at least something as close to a point estimate in a point-prediction model).

What I'm doing now is to just change the loss function of the model to the L2 loss so that I can obtain point estimates (conditional mean) with the same learner.

I'm wondering if it's legit if I just change the loss function in order obtain point estimates, and use the PIs for each sample to accompany the corresponding point estimates?

Welcome any thoughts or advice!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by legit. There is in principle no problem if you report means together with predictions intervals.

However, as you are already using quantile regression, a more natural thing to do is to report the median together with your prediction intervals. If you compute your prediction intervals from the $\alpha$- and $(1-\alpha)$-quantile for $\alpha < 0.5$, then the median can be interpreted as the edge case of these intervals when $\alpha = 0.5$. It is thus in some sense the "smallest prediction interval".

An application where this approach was used is the Covid-19 forecast hub for the US, see for instance
[here](https://forecasters.org/blog/2020/10/28/comparing-ensemble-approaches-for-short-term-probabilistic-covid-19-forecasts-in-the-u-s/), in particular their Figure 1.